# Case Assignment Rule Email Not Working

Tags: community, case, assignment-rules

My salesforce env is developer sandbox and I am working on case assignment rule, if that required criteria match then I am assigning case to a particular queue. That is working fine if I see the created case details.
**Issue:**
I selected a email template in case assignment rule but that is not sending email to target queue member. Also, I tried Assigned to my personal email instead Queue but still no email.

**Settings which I did:**

1. Email Deliverability Setting: Access Level is All Email
   [image]
2. Support Settings checked Notify Default Case Owner
   [image]

Is there anything missing from my sandbox configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the checkbox in queue "Send Email to Members" as well as the checkbox in assignment rule "Email".So,can you please double check on the Assignment rule to make sure you have checked it.

Thank you!

Comment: they are already checked. I tried email feature with Workflow rules, that is working fine from there but not from Case Assignment Rules.